# Detect scroll up and scroll down offset in ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I want to detect the y-delta of the scrolled value on a `ListView`. There are already similiar questions and solutions on stackoverflow but I need the scrolled values.

**Method 1:**
One of the solutions suggest to use a wrapper class for `ListView` and override the `onScrollChanged` method but the passed values to this method are always zero except when you fling the `ListView`.

**Method 2:**
There is also another way to detect scroll ups and downs by observing the first visible item in the list but this is not helpful in my case because the events are only detected when yout scroll up or down the whole item.

**What I want to do:** I want to implement a snap on the first item of my `ListView`. So when the bottom of the first item is visible the list should smooth scroll to the top and when the user scrolls down from the top the snap should be unlocked.
For the smooth scroll to the top I could use *Method 1* but to unlock the snap I need to know if the user is scrolling down even though the first visible item is still the same.